# GWT developer plugin not supported now in Chrome

Tags: gwt

I was developing GWT application but as I came to know google doesn't support  GWT developer plugin for Google Chrome now, provide me any other method to test my application of GWT

Comment: Use SuperDevMode. It is supported by any browser.

Comment: please provide me any reference on how to use it

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html

Answer (score 2):

[SuperDevMode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html) is the new way of debugging GWT applications.

If you want to use the older GWT developer plugin then you can if you use an older browser. The latest version of Firefox that can be used is [version 24](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/24.0esr/). IE 11 works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

> GWT Development Mode will no longer be available for Chrome sometime
>   in 2014, so we improved alternate ways of debugging. There are
>   improvements to Super Dev Mode, asserts, console logging, and error
>   messages.[Read Note](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_1)

[for more information about super dev mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html)